# Is there a conic tangent to each of the six lines comprising a conic-inscribed hexagon?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $H$ be a hexagon formed by six points lying on a conic in the plane.

Is there a conic tangent to each of the six lines comprising $H$?

Comment: If we change *H* from a hexagon to two triangles, there must be a conic tangent to each of the six lines. I'm looking forward an easy way to prove it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271783

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no. The necessary and sufficient condition for this to hold is that the main diagonals of hexagon are concurrent. This is called Brianchon's theorem.