# A conic tangent to two triangles

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

I'm trying to prove the claim:

> Two triangles inscribed in a conic section, there must be another conic tangent to the six edges of the two triangles.

[image]

The problem looks simpler than this question: [A conic inside a hexagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853544/a-conic-inside-a-hexagon) , but I haven't found a way to use Pascal + Desargues + Brianchon directly.

Here is my approach:

1. Pascal's theorem tells us that *AD*∩*BE* lies on line *GJ*;
2. Pappus's theorem applying on *ALE* and *BHD* tells us that *G*, *AD*∩*BE* and *LD*∩*HE* are collinear, so *LD*∩*HE* lies on *GJ*;
3. Pappus's theorem applying on *LKE* and *HID* tells us that *LI*∩*HK*, *LD*∩*HE* and *J* are collinear, so *LI*∩*HK* lies on *GJ*, i.e. *GJ*, *HK* and *LI* are concurrent;
4. The converse of Brianchon's theorem tells us that there must be a conic tangent to the hexagon *GHIJKL*.

Are there any simple ways to prove it?

Comment: English issue: You mean *inscribed in*. It was quite confusing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is already pretty short, but it can be shorter.  For the hexagon $\pmb{H}=AGBDJE$ you've shown that the diagonals $AD,GJ,BE$ are concurrent.  By the converse of Brianchon, $\pmb{H}$ has an inscribed conic.  But the sides of $\pmb{H}$ are the same as the sides of the triangles, so we're done.